# Best way to position buttons (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what's the best way to position buttons?
I'm trying to make this website teacher has asked me to do however I don't know how to position buttons correctly.

This is what I have:
[image: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/7508/exuc.png][/img]

This is what I need to have:
[image: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/1023/n2qx.png]

src:

.css file
http://pastebin.com/3mZXzkzS

```
/*---------------*/   #logo {
    width:167px;
    height:96px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    float:left;
    margin: 24px;
   }


#info{
 display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 175px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../images/info_box_1.png');
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

#mang1, #uusp, #jatka {

 display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../images/Button_black_small.png');
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:5px;
}


.kool1, .kool3  {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../images/button_test.png');
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;

}


#aru, #aru, #too, #teams, #sqn, #kalend, #plan{
   display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../images/Button_3_small.png');
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
 margin-top:5px;
}


.kool2, .log  {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../images/button_test2.png');
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.lEnglish, .lEstonian, .lRussian , #clear{
margin-top:25px;
text-decoration: none;
}


#tile_mid, #tile_top , #tile_mid_pt2{
    margin-left: 200px;
}


.but1, .but2, .but3{
display: block;
float: left;
height: 30px;
width: 162px;
background-image: url('../images/button_test3.png');
text-align: center;
margin-right:2px;
margin-top:4px;
}

.but4, .but5 {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 30px;
width: 162px;
background-image: url('../images/button_test3.png');
text-align: center;
margin-right:2px;
margin-top:4px;
}




.kool3 {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

.html file
http://pastebin.com/VQZx44PG

```
<base href="http://dynama.eek.ee">

    <div text="#000000" style="background:#ffffff url('http://dynama.eek.ee/images/background.png') repeat scroll top center; height:1000px;">
 <div id="logo"><a href="http://dynama.eek.ee"><img src="./images/logo.png"/></a></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="info"><a href="http://dynama.eek.ee"></a>Information:</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div id="mang1">Mäng 1 AKTIIVNE</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="uusp">Uus periood</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="jatka">Jätka</div>

   <div class="clear"></div>

  <div id="aru">ARUANDED</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="too">TOOTED</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="teams">TIIMID</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="sqn">SQNUMID</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
<div id="kalend">KALENDAR</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
<div id="plan">QPPEPLAN M+U</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>


      <div id="tile_top">
     <div class="kool1">
    <a href="#" class="kool1">Kool 1</a> </div>
    <a href="#" class="kool2">Kool 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="kool3">Kool 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="log">Log out</a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lEnglish" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_eng.png"/> </a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lRussian" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_rus.png"/> </a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lEstonian" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_est.png"/> </a>



</div>

<div id="tile_mid">
    <a href="#" class="but1">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="but2">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="but3">Button 3</a>
    </div>
        <img id="clear" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/clear.png"/>
    <div id="tile_mid_pt2">
    <a href="#" class="but4">Button 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="but5">Button 5</a>
    </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>








</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: We don't do homework.

Comment: Please use the built-in image uploader so the image links don't rot.

Comment: Hey, I just asked how to position buttons properly. Is that a problem?

Comment: You should start by learning the basics of HTML, not everything has to be a `<div>`, then look for tutorials for a two column layout

Comment: PS. I cant post images cause it tells me that I need to have reputation of 10. Which I had untill I created this, but now, I am no longer able to upload images.

Comment: PS. How am I suppose to learn some thing if I instantly get flamed? Rather return to 3d modelling than waste my time with this rotten, unfriendly community that literally hates newcomers for no obvious reason.

Comment: "How am I suppose to learn some thing if I instantly get flamed?" The problem is the community feels you haven't even tried to learn before asking.  This isn't a spoon-fed community.  We expect you to attempt to solve a problem first, then ask questions if you get stuck.  Only after you've exhausted your available resources should you ask questions.  There are thousands of pages and resources available that can teach you this basic positioning technique.  Asking such a question only demonstrates that you're not willing to solve the problem yourself, but have others do it for you.

Comment: I've tried googling 'button positioning in css' and havent found anything useful for me.

Comment: Think about a big container, divided in two sections. Both sections float to left. Inside section one put your sidebar. Inside section two put buttons. Positions can be done with margins for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code...

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Dynama </title>

            <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>      

 <body text="#000000" style="background:#ffffff url('images/background.png') repeat scroll top center; height:1000px;">
 <div id="logo"><a href="http://dynama.eek.ee"><img src="./images/logo.png"/></a></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div>
 <div id="info"><a href="http://dynama.eek.ee"></a>Information:</div>
 <div id="tile_top">
     <div class="kool1">
 <a href="#" class="kool1">Kool 1</a> </div>
<a href="#" class="kool2">Kool 2</a>
<a href="#" class="kool3">Kool 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="log">Log out</a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lEnglish" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_eng.png"/> </a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lRussian" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_rus.png"/> </a>
    <a href="#"><img class="lEstonian" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/Flag_est.png"/> </a>     


  </div>
   <div id="tile_mid">
    <a href="#" class="but1">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="but2">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="but3">Button 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


   <div id="mang1">Mäng 1 AKTIIVNE</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="uusp">Uus periood</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="jatka">Jätka</div>

   <div class="clear"></div>

   <div id="aru">ARUANDED</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="too">TOOTED</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="teams">TIIMID</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="sqn">SQNUMID</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="kalend">KALENDAR</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="plan">QPPEPLAN M+U</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>




            <img id="clear" height="25px" width="45px" src="./images/clear.png"/>
     <div id="tile_mid_pt2">
    <a href="#" class="but4">Button 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="but5">Button 5</a>
    </div>

     <div class="clear"></div>      

    </body>


    </html>
```